# Instagram authenticaton for self feed?

Tags: php, instagram

I'm trying to get photos from my Instagram-Feed but everytime Il have to login in my Authentication-Popup, although i use my access token from DB

```
//FIRST TIME
$array = array(
        'client_id'=>'XXX',
        'client_secret' => 'XXX',
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URL,
        'code' => $_GET['code']
        );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $access_token = $res['access_token'];

    //SAVE ACCESS_TOKEN INTO DB 

    //NEXT TIME
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token='.$db['access_token'].'&client_id='.$array['client_id'].'&client_secret='.$array['client_secret'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double check the value of $db['access_token']; is it getting passed?

Comment: `$db['access_token']` is correct. For testing i had store the value in a variable.

Comment: Can copy paste the request url in browser directly and see what u get?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there was a mistake in the lines above this.
I requested the `code` every time and this redirect shows me the login form.

**Before:**

```
if(!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    header('location: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri='.REDIRECT_URL.'&response_type=code');
}else{
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/';
    // ...
```

**After:**

```
if(!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($access_token) ) {
    header('location: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri='.REDIRECT_URL.'&response_type=code');
}else{
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/';
    // ...
```

Now it works fine.